# Open chrome extension's popup window on event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

trying to build a chrome extension that allows you to highlight text, do right click and on click send that text to extension's browser popup and open it.

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "send text to popup", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: function(info, tab) {
    //console.log(info.selectionText);
    sendtopopup(info.selectionText);
  }
});

function sendtopopup(text) {
  
 console.log(text);
 
  
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({result: text}, console.log("runtime is executed on background"));

  

} // end send pop up
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* Add styles for the popup here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>below should be hihglighted text</h4>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <p id="result2"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.result;
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "sameple text to check listener";
      }
    );
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.result;
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "2222222sameple text to check listener";
      }
    );
    
  </script>
</html>
```

this is the manifest.json file code:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "send text to popup",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Sends highlighted text to popup",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus"

  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

is there a way that right click function execution the extension's popup window would open from browser extension icon?

Comment: `chrome.action.openPopup()`

Comment: Manifest V2 is being phased out, I'd recommend switching to V3. See [Manifest V2 support timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

Comment: @Anilkumar can you provide a more in depth example? how hould i use the function? where to place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a way to have the popup open when a context menu item is clicked. In Manifest V3, a new API is available in Chrome Canary (`action.openPopup`) which would allow this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1245093

I wrote a blog post about the status of this API across browsers and some of the work that is being done to make the behaviour consistent: https://oliverdunk.com/2022/11/13/extensions-open-popup

I'm hopeful we'll take the API to stable soon to make this possible.

Comment: modified to v3, open popup does not work, not recognized.

Comment: Have you tried in Chrome Canary? As mentioned, this API is not available in stable yet.

Comment: in chrome canary is not giving any error, but pop still does not open

Comment: update: it now does, but not every single time

Comment: Are you definitely using chrome.action.openPopup in an MV3 extension?

Comment: yes, it's on manifest v3

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has `openPopup` api.

```
chrome.action.openPopup(
  options?: OpenPopupOptions,
  callback?: function,
);

OpenPopupOptions :windowId
```

Read more at [chrome.action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-openPopup)

Comment: this is what i get " Error in event handler: TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function"

Comment: It doesn't work in brave browser. vs code show false error. Provide your browser info.
I already used in 2-3 extensions.

Comment: Content.js may not recognize this function (i don't test ) . Test with background.js.

Comment: can you please tell me one of these extensions? so i can inspect functionality and code?

Comment: ok, i was able to launch in in canary. how do i parse variables from background.js to popup when it gets loaded with open popup?

Comment: is this because v3 background js doesn't have access to DOM ?

Comment: figured this out, used content_script

Answer (score 0):

I have checked, `chrome.action.openPopup` is for devChennel only.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-openPopup

Comment: kinda wierd it's not up for non dev browser yet.